# Why does rebuilt widget appear in addition to original widget instead of replacing it?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to display an image of a window, consisting of a number of panes, at 80% of the size of the browser tab (using Flutter web). And to have the image automatically resized whenever the browser tab is resized.

It works, except that the "new" image is overlaid on top of the old image, instead of replacing it, as shown in these before and after screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Minimum working code is on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/aca3cefae20411fdbe1e2c123c5a6a16). Just resize your browser window, or swipe the divider between the code and the output left and right to see the effect.

How do I stop it from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding elements to the list in the build method so whenever the screen is rebuilt it adds new copies of the element.

Simple fix would be to empty the list before adding a new element to it.

So you can just use `wholeWindow = <Positioned>[];` in the build method before adding the elements or you can declare the List inside the build method.